# Django update_or_create()

Tags: python, django, filter

I'm trying to use Django get_or_create | update_or_create() but for some reason when the except is called because there are no rows that matches the filter (on try), I receive the following error:

TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <SimpleLazyObject: <User: admin>>.

```
class SelectedWallet(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    wallet = models.name = models.ForeignKey(Wallet, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateField(verbose_name='Created', auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateField(verbose_name='Modified', auto_now=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='selected_wallet_created_by', blank=True, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='selected_wallet_modified_by', blank=True, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'myapp_selected_wallet'
        ordering = ['wallet__name']
        verbose_name = 'Selected_Wallet'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Selected_Wallets'

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return self.wallet.name
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SelectedWallet, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def select_wallet(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        wallet = request.POST['wallet_id']
        user = get_current_user()
        created_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime ("%Y-%m-%d")

        # First method attempt
        defaults = {
            'created': created_time,
            'created_by_id': user,
            'modified_by_id': user,
            'user_id': user,
            'wallet_id': wallet
        }
        try:
            obj = SelectedWallet.objects.get(user_id=user)
            for key, value in defaults.items():
                setattr(obj, key, value)
            obj.save()
        except SelectedWallet.DoesNotExist:
            obj = SelectedWallet.objects.create(
                created = created_time,
                created_by_id = user,
                modified_by_id = user,
                user_id = user,
                wallet_id = wallet
            )
            obj.save(force_insert=True)
        
        # Second method attempt (both receive the same error)
        # obj, created = SelectedWallet.objects.update_or_create(
        #         id = 2,
        #         created = created_time,
        #         created_by_id = user,
        #         modified_by_id = user,
        #         user_id = user,
        #         wallet_id = wallet
        # )

        selected_wallet = (SelectedWallet.objects
                           .filter(user_id=user)
                           .filter(wallet_id=wallet)
                           )
        
        return JsonResponse(list(selected_wallet.values('wallet_id')), safe = False)
```

Comment: your code doesn't have `update_or_create` in it

Comment: Is true sorry, but in the end the idea is to save information in db, using or not update_or_create.

Comment: from the code written it seems like you want `get_or_create` instead, current use of `defaults` doesn't seem to make sense (just updating the `id` to the `id` it already had?)

Answer (score 1):

You could try `objects.get_or_create()`. This takes your `User` and `Wallet` objects and requested them from the DB. If they exist they are assigned to `obj` and `created` is set to `False`. If no objects exist for that user and wallet a new object is created (`obj`) and `created` is set to `True`. Then you can make any edits to the model `obj` you need. This avoids the need for the `try`.

```python
class ModelSelectedWallet(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    wallet =  models.ForeignKey(ModelWallet, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateField(verbose_name='Created', auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateField(verbose_name='Modified', auto_now=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='selected_wallet_created_by', blank=True, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='selected_wallet_modified_by', blank=True, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)


def select_wallet(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        wallet_id = request.POST['wallet_id']
        user = get_current_user()
        wallet = Wallet.objects.get(id=wallet_id) # import Wallet from models.py

        
        obj, created = ModelSelectedWallet.objects.get_or_create(user=user, wallet=wallet)
        if created:
            obj.created_by = user
            obj.modified_by = user
            obj.save()
        else:
            pass # do any updates you need here. pass is simply a command to skip this else. Replace with what you need to update.
```

Note that the convention for model naming is as you have it but without the "Model" - so you should write `SelectedWallet` and `Wallet` and re-run your migrations.

**Edit**

As suggested by @Anentropic you could assign defaults to your get_or_create() automatically populating the `created_by` and `modified_by` fields:

```python
obj, created = ModelSelectedWallet.objects.get_or_create(
    user=user, wallet=wallet, 
    defaults={'created_by': user, 'modified_by': user}
)
```

which will work well provided the user returned by `get_current_user()` is the `user` who the `SelectedWallet` should be linked with (i.e. the requestor is the user themself and not an administrator, for instance).

Comment: I think this answer could be improved by specifying `created_by` and `modified_by` in the `defaults` arg dict to the `get_or_create` call, avoiding the need to update them and re-save the instance https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create

Comment: Sure - good point. Never noticed that functionality before to be honest so thank you. I've left the initial suggestion in to highlight how one could use the tuple returned by a `get_or_create()` call if it is helpful to @APorto

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. I update the question following the suggestion that you have made, but still have issue when try to create new record.

Answer (score 0):

For now I made this.

```
def select_wallet(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        wallet = request.POST['wallet_id']
        user = get_current_user()
        created_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime ("%Y-%m-%d")

        defaults = {
            'created': created_time,
            'created_by_id': user,
            'modified_by_id': user,
            'user_id': user,
            'wallet_id': wallet
        }
        try:
            obj = SelectedWallet.objects.get(user_id=user)
            for key, value in defaults.items():
                setattr(obj, key, value)
            obj.save()
        except SelectedWallet.DoesNotExist:
            created = created_time
            modified = created_time
            created_by_id = user.id
            modified_by_id = user.id
            user_id = user.id
            wallet_id = wallet
            
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute('INSERT INTO `myapp`.`myapp_selected_wallet` (created, modified, created_by_id, modified_by_id, user_id, wallet_id) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', [created, modified, created_by_id, modified_by_id, user_id, wallet_id])

        selected_wallet = (SelectedWallet.objects
                           .filter(user_id=user)
                           .filter(wallet_id=wallet)
                           )
        
        return JsonResponse(list(selected_wallet.values('wallet_id')), safe = False)
```